# Remove index.html URL after redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have the following commands in my .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
Redirect /index.html /main/index.html

and it gets me to http://mydomain.com/main/index.html

The question is how can i remove mydomain.com/main/index.html URL after redirection and make it in the browser just mydomain.com/ ?

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect /index.html http://mydomain.com
```

That should do it